# Study of relative class number of 'non-abelian' CM field by using L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions, computational-number-theory

I'm currently interested in finding good upper bounds for the relative class numbers of non-abelian CM-fields.

So I'm looking for some references to learn the techniques that can be useful.

So far, I have given some looks at some papers on the '**class number one problem for CM-field**' or '**computation of the class numbers of CM-field**'.

But I'm not successful at finding the good references for the novice in this field yet.

It seems to me that the techniques used in those papers are on the **boundary** between algebraic number theory and analytic number theory.

And also I feel that this research seem to have a long history, so when I try to read some papers, for example of **Stephane Louboutin**, it seems to be already technically advanced.

So I feel that just the knowledge of the analytic class number formula and some experience with the generalized Bernoulli numbers (abelian CM-fields) is not enough.

My objective for now is to learn the **general** strategy for studying the relative class number of non-abelian CM-field.

So can you recommend me good references?

I have studied the analytic class number formula in the book of Serge Lang, I have familiarity with the contents of chapter 4 of Washington's book and p-adic L-functions.

But I haven't studied other theories of L-functions yet. (for example Tate's thesis)

Thank you very much!